# Bootstrap - Submit file input form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this Bootstrap from model, and I do not know why the **submit** button does not sent the file, it sent nothing.

```
<form action="myPage.php" class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                    <div class="input-group input-large">
                        <div class="form-control uneditable-input input-fixed input-medium" data-trigger="fileinput">
                            <i class="fa fa-file fileinput-exists"></i>&nbsp;
                                <span class="fileinput-filename"> </span>
                        </div>
                            <span class="input-group-addon btn default btn-file">
                            <span class="fileinput-new"> CHOOSE FILE </span>
                            <span class="fileinput-exists"> CHANGE </span>
                            <input type="file" name="..."> </span>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="input-group-addon btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> DELETE </a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     <div class="form-actions">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                 <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-outline grey-salsa">Cancel</a>
             </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

all links are available

Comment: Where is the submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :
`<form action="myPage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

`<div class="form-group">`
   `<label for="exampleInputFile">CHOOSE FILE</label>`
   `<input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">`
   `<p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>`
 `</div>`

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>`
`</form>`

Comment: First I forgot enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: and there was some error in the action file... Now all works fine, thank you

Answer (score 0):

you are using link ,You need submit button 
`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>` and your form is messing ">" 
`<form action="myPage.php" class="form-horizontal form-bordered"`

Comment: the ">" miss just here and not in my original code.

Comment: So add  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" cause you uploading file ,imean '<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'

Comment: do not work also! the problem is in the submit button part